# Prove that if for each x,y from P exists sup(x,y) and inf(x,y)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let (P,$\le$) be an ordered set. Prove that if for each x,y from P exists sup(x,y) and inf(x,y) then exists sup(A) and inf(A) for any finite A $\subseteq$ P.

I don`t know how to make a proof of it, maybe someone could help me?

Comment: Try induction on the size of $A$.  Note:  usually for finite sets one speaks of max and min, rather than sup and inf.  Do you mean something different than max and min?  Since the set is ordered we must have (exactly) one of $x<y, y<x, x=y$  Or did you mean "partially ordered"?

Comment: @lulu well actually it is not stated that it is partialy or linear ordered, just siad ORDERED.

Comment: @lulu about sup and inf it is not just about maximums, sup means least upper bound and inf greates lower bound

Comment: Well, in a totally ordered set (which is what I take "ordered" to mean), then we have a clear notion of max and min in any finite set.  If you want partially ordered instead, you should edit your post to say so.

Comment: @lulu i don`t know if its is partially ordered or totally.

Comment: @lulu but i think then it is possible to take a totally ordered set

Comment: Well, we can't guess your intent here.  In any case, I think induction is the way to go.  The case in which $|A|=1$ is trivial and you have been handed the case of $|A|=2$.  Now try $|A|=3$, to get a sense of how the inductive step goes.

Comment: @lulu yeah about 1 and 2 it is obviuse but how to prove it for 3 and so on?

Comment: Well, try.  Suppose your elements are $a,b,c$.  First solve for max or sup of $a,b$.  Now, what's the next step?

Comment: @lulu Wel sup of a,b is b if a$\le$b , but i can not add some C and say that c is sup of a,b,c

Comment: Again, try.  If $M$ is the sup of $a,b$ then it is natural to consider $\sup(M,c)$.  What can you say about that in relation to $a,b$?

Comment: @lulu well then c will be supremum, but only if M $\le$ c

Comment: Well, what if $M>c$?  There's no point in just considering some of the possible cases...